# Gsheet Add partial hours to start time for calculating end hour

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula which will calculate `Exit` time by adding `Total Hours` to `Entry` time

`E2` - Total Hours - `7.5`

`F2` - Entry - `08:45`

`G2` - Exit - `=F2+TIME(E2,0,0)`

I expect `G2` to be `16:30`, but it results in `15:45`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the decimal potion of the hours in E2 as minutes. The TIME function expects only integers as arguments.

The correct result would seem to be `16:15` not `16:30`.

```
=F2+TIME(INT(E2), MOD(E2, 1)*60, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear to me because `08:45` plus `7.5` hours is `16:15` for me.

But [Docs Editors Help for TIME](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?hl=en) states:

> TIME will silently truncate decimal values input into the function,
>   e.g. an hour of 12.75 will be interpreted as 12.

So `7.5` will be interpreted as `7`.

But 1 hour is 1/24 day. So `7.5/24`= `07:30`.

So `=F2+E2/24` should result in `16:15`.